# Exhaustive search / generate each combination of an expression tree

Tags: c#, tree, expression, expression-trees, visitor-pattern

I'm playing with a basic Expression Tree optimiser to build query plans.  When parsing a Tree, I can make decisions as to how is "best" to construct it, depending on a weighting I can assign to each operation.

If I have a simple tree, with 2 choices on how to perform an action, I'd like to be able to generate both variations of the tree, and can then compare the weighting of each to see what is the most efficient.

For example, the code below will allow me to construct two variations of the Expression Tree Join operation : one with a `MergeJoinExpression` and one with a `NestedLoopJoinExpression`

```
class Customer
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
}
class Orders
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}

class MergeJoinExpresion : JoinExpression
{
}

class NestLoopJoinExpresion : JoinExpression
{
}

class Visitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public List<Expression> GetPlans(Expression expr)
    {
        // ???
    }

    override VisitJoin(JoinExpression join)
    {
        // For this join, I can return the following (trite example)
        // return MergeJoinExpresion
        // return NestLoopJoinExpresion

        return base.VisitJoin(join);
    }
}
```

How can I construct a method that will generate each variation of tree and return them to me?

```
class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             var query = from c in customers
                        join o in orders on c.Id equals o.CustomerId
                        select new
                        {
                            CustomerId = c.Id,
                            OrderId = o.Id
                        };


            var plans = new Visitor().GetPlans(query);
        }
}
```

Can anyone show me how I can modify the `Visitor` Class `GetPlans` method to generate these variations?

**EDIT - something like:**

```
class Visitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private List<Expression> exprs = new List<Expression>();

    public List<Expression> GetPlans(Expression expr)
    {
        Visit(expr);    
        return exprs;
    }

    override VisitJoin(JoinExpression join)
    {
        // For this join, I can return the following (trite example)
        // return MergeJoinExpresion
        // return NestLoopJoinExpresion      
        var choices = new Expression[] { MergeJoinExpresion.Create(join), NestLoopJoinExpresion.Create(join) };

        foreach(var choice in choices)
        {
             var cloned = Cloner.Clone(choice);
             var newTree = base.VisitJoin(cloned);
             exprs.Add(newTree);
        }

        return base.VisitJoin(join);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure a visitor is the best way to do it. VisitJoin must return multiple variants that it generated. All callers must support multiple variants and themselves potentially generate multiple variants. Join planning usually is not being done in this simple exhaustive manner anyway because time complexity would be exponential.

Comment: The join was just the simplest example I could think of in a very simplistic example.   I'm using an expression tree to generate different plans - and need a way of generating each possible outcome (whether its for a Join, or, something else.)     So question is how to generate different versions of a Tree that can be generated during Visiting the nodes.  It's so I can double check that the Query plan I have selected is the best, by checking against an exhaustive search...

Comment: I guess you can make it work if you make the visitor methods return IEnumerable<Expression> instead of Expression.

Comment: I think that's not a good idea.  The Visitor must conform to the base visitor (and only return Expressions).  What needs to happen (although I am hitting a mental block here) is - work out how many variations can be made and construct a new tree for each variation.

Comment: You need to change the "base visitor" as well. No way to channel multiple expressions through a single one. You don't just need variations on one join node, you need variations on the variations themselves. Btw, if you wrote recursive methods to traverse the tree this would be easy and obvious. The return value would be an IEnumerable. The only question is how to adapt the visitor pattern to do this as well.

Comment: I do not need to change the base visitor.  Both MergeJoinExpresion and NestLoopJoinExpresion extend the JoinExpression  class, and can be returned from the VisitJoin method.  The visitor and the base visitor (not shown) can handle this without being changed.   When I have my two expression tree's created, I can visit each tree, check to see what type of JoinExpression there is to determine its projected complexity.

Comment: The issues you have listed "no way to channel multiple expressions through a single one. You don't just need variations on one join node, you need variations on the variations themselves." are not issues for me.   The issue I am facing is determining that I have X choices, and generating a tree for each choice...

Comment: And how are you going to return multiple variants if the return type is Expression?

Comment: Each variant extends "Expression", so can be returned by the visitor.  The base visitor knows about the JoinExpression and the checks whether the Expression is or can be a JoinExpression (which is true for both the MergeJoinExpresion  and NestLoopJoinExpresion ) and process these expressions as if there were a Join (the visitor checks if the Expression is / extends a Join, and handles it as such).   I reiterate, this is already working and not the question I am asking.  I need to be able to clone a tree at the point of decision, for each possible decision, and keep a collection of these trees

Comment: That's new to me that the cloning is the problem. My suggestion for that would be to make tree nodes immutable. Cloning then involves only cloning a single node which is easy. Immutability is very convenient when working with ASTs in general.

Comment: Cloning a tree is not the issue either, I have a method that carries this out.  The issue is, at the point of decision, I need to clone the tree, add my first choice to the tree (return the MergeJoinExpresion ), and continue to visit that tree.  Once that cloned tree has finished visitation, I need to then return the second choice for the tree (return the NestLoopJoinExpresion ), and continue to visit that tree.    This is where I am having the block - unsure how is best to do this!  Assuming a variable List<Expression>, clone, add the new Expression, then continue... This is where I am stuck

Comment: OK, so that's what I thought and what I told you how to solve. You return a list of generated variants. Can you tell me why that would not work? So far you stated you don't need that but it seems it would do just what you want.

Comment: Please see edited question for example – it is where / how to generate the variants...

Comment: That can't work because exprs will now contain all kinds of internal nodes. You need to return, not store to something global.

Comment: "That can't work because exprs will now contain all kinds of internal nodes" - are you sure about this?   I use this method to rewrite the tree (which works with very complex trees, handling joins, group joins, aggregates etc ), and do not have issues with internal nodes...

Comment: If it works why are you here? Not sure what you mean by that comment therefore. Isn't it obvious to you that exprs will now contain local nodes? How can this possibly work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94111/discussion-between-jack-and-usr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to start with we'll create a visitor that will just help us extract a list of `JoinExpression` objects from an `Expression`:

```
internal class FindJoinsVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private List<JoinExpression> expressions = new List<JoinExpression>();
    protected override Expression VisitJoin(JoinExpression join)
    {
        expressions.Add(join);
        return base.VisitJoin(join);
    }
    public IEnumerable<JoinExpression> JoinExpressions
    {
        get
        {
            return expressions;
        }
    }
}
public static IEnumerable<JoinExpression> FindJoins(
    this Expression expression)
{
    var visitor = new FindJoinsVisitor();
    visitor.Visit(expression);
    return visitor.JoinExpressions;
}
```

Next we'll use the following method, taken from [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx), to get the Cartesian Product of a sequence of sequences:

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(
    this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences) 
{ 
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() }; 
    return sequences.Aggregate( 
        emptyProduct, 
        (accumulator, sequence) => 
            from accseq in accumulator 
            from item in sequence 
            select accseq.Concat(new[] {item})); 
}
```

Next we'll create a visitor that takes a sequence of pairs of expressions, and replaces all instances of the first expression in the pair with the second:

```
internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Expression, Expression> lookup;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Dictionary<Expression, Expression> pairsToReplace)
    {
        lookup = pairsToReplace;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        if(lookup.ContainsKey(node))
            return base.Visit(lookup[node]);
        else
            return base.Visit(node);
    }
}

public static Expression ReplaceAll(this Expression expression,
    Dictionary<Expression, Expression> pairsToReplace)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(pairsToReplace).Visit(expression);
}

public static Expression ReplaceAll(this Expression expression,
    IEnumerable<Tuple<Expression, Expression>> pairsToReplace)
{
    var lookup = pairsToReplace.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Item1, pair => pair.Item2);
    return new ReplaceVisitor(lookup).Visit(expression);
}
```

And finally we put everything together by finding all of the join expressions in our expression, project those out to a sequence of pairs where the `JoinExpression` is the first item in the pair, and the second is each possible replacement value.  From there we can take the Cartesian Product of that to get all of the combinations of pairs of expression replacements.  Finally we can project each combination of replacements into the expression that results from actually replacing all of those pairs in the original expression:

```
public static IEnumerable<Expression> AllJoinCombinations(Expression expression)
{
    var combinations = expression.FindJoins()
        .Select(join => new Tuple<Expression, Expression>[]
        {
            Tuple.Create<Expression, Expression>(join, new NestLoopJoinExpresion(join)), 
            Tuple.Create<Expression, Expression>(join, new MergeJoinExpresion(join)),
        })
        .CartesianProduct();

    return combinations.Select(combination => expression.ReplaceAll(combination));
}
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution because it does not require altering the visitor to return sequences instead of singletons. But how can it work despite the fact that for each join you only create the alternatives once? It seems the alternatives must be created for each replacement operation because the subtrees are different each time because of child replacements. The replacements are dependent on the child subtree after replacement.

Comment: @usr You scared me for a second, but the fix is actually very easy.  By having `ReplaceAll` visit the node being replaced, it'll end up traversing the entire tree of the NestLoop or Merge expression and replace all of the nested `JoinExpression` elements based on the mappings provided, so all that needed to change was adding a `base.VIsit` call on the result of the lookup before returning it.

Comment: Cool. Would like to see some convincing unit tests for this code, though :) A good case for exhaustive testing I think.

Comment: @Servy - ideal solution, you understood exactly what I was asking and provided an elegant solution I can modify and scale this to solve my issue.... Great stuf

Answer (score 1):

You need immutable trees for sure.

Create a class:

```
class JoinOptionsExpression: JoinExpression {
    public IEnumerable<JoinExpression> Options {get; private set;}
    private JoinOptionsExpression(){}
    public static JoinOptionsExpression Create(IEnumerable<JoinExpression> options){
        return new JoinOptionsExpression{Options = options.ToList().AsReadOnly()}; // you can improve this probably
    }
}
```

Then in your VisitJoin method return the Options, and return all choices:

```
private List<Dictionary<JoinOptionsExpression,int>> selections = new List<Dictionary<JoinOptionsExpression,int>>{new Dictionary<JoinOptionsExpression,int>()};
override VisitJoin(JoinExpression join)
{
    var choices = new Expression[] { MergeJoinExpresion.Create(join), NestLoopJoinExpresion.Create(join) };
    List<Expression> exprs = new List<Expression>();
    foreach(var choice in choices)
    {
         var cloned = Cloner.Clone(choice);
         var newTree = base.VisitJoin(cloned);
         exprs.Add(newTree);
    }
    var result = JoinOptionsExpression.Create(exprs);
    // now add all choices
    if (exprs.Count > 0)
        foreach (selection in selections.ToList()) // to make sure your don't modify during enumeration, you can improve this too
        {
            selection.Add(result, 0);
            for (i=1; i<exprs.Count; i++)
            {
                var copy= new Dictionary<JoinOptionsExpression, int>(selection);
                copy[result] = i;
                selections.Add(copy);
            }
        }
    return result;
}
```

Then you will need a second Visitor, that derives from the framework visitor, and has no other reason, just extract your options:

```
class OptionsExtractor:ExpressionVisitor
{
    public IEnumerable<Expression> Extract(Expression expression, List<Dictionary<JoinOptionsExpression,int>> selections)
    {
        foreach(var selection in selections)
        {
            currentSelections = selection;
            yield return Visit(expression);
        }
    }
    private Dictionary<JoinOptionsExpression,int> currentSelections;
    override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        var opts = node as JoinOptionsExpression;
        if (opts != null)
            return base.Visit(opts.Options.ElementAt(currentSelections[opts]);
        else
            return base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

Anyways an exhausive search can quickly explode in your face, i guess you know that.
Disclaimer: I just typed this in this editor, it won't even compile probably, but you should be able to get the idea.

Comment: JoinOptionsExpression is a hack. It would be better to pass a collection right away. Besides that this is the right approach and I have advocated it in the comments.

Comment: @usr: Yes, JoinOptionsExpression is a hack to group all possible subnodes in one node. For me this would allow a better debugging overview, having one tree with all options in it.

Comment: @MBoros, great solution - you understood exactly what I was asking and provided a workable solution. The only reason I am not marking this as the answer is the JoinOptionsExpression class - I dont want a new expression type who's only purpose is to handle an exhaustive search of Joins, especially as I'll need a number of these for different Expression types, and can solve the overall problem without these. Great answer though.